# Prepend all sass rules to "scope" css

Tags: sass

I'm trying to scope all my sass rules within a `#scope` id.

I can't figure out how to prepend all the css rules with `#scope` when using the sass ampersand. Is it possible to achieve this, if so how?

```
//current sass 
#scope {
    .element {
        color: green;
        .modifier & { color: red; }
    }  
    .element2 { color: blue; }
}

//desired output
#scope .element { color: green; }
#scope .modifier .element { color: red; }
#scope .element2 { color: blue; }


//actual output
#scope .element { color: green; }
.modifier #scope .element { color: red; }
#scope .element2 { color: blue; }
```

Comment: How many hoops are you willing to go through to make this work?  You're going to be better off changing your design.

Comment: @cimmanon Changing the design is probably not an option. Our application is javascript driven and is included into as an other company's page. The scope with an #id is a way to ensure our specificity. We do prepend the #id with grunt today, I just figured it could be solved in sass, the Grunt option might be the better one...

Comment: I meant in regards to nesting.  Nesting is not a requirement.  Your desire to nest them *this* way is more trouble than it's worth.  Just reverse the nesting order or don't nest at all.  Either that or be prepared to add several lines of code to produce the desired results.

Comment: @cimmanon Yeah I got that, thanks. It's more convenient to solve our implementation with Grunt or refactor the nesting.